# What is the meaning/purpose of the [indicators] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The main site has the [indicators](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicators) tag, but I can't seem to figure out what it means. It has no tag wiki, but there are 6 questions with the tag:

1. a question talking about generosity in the world happiness score (now closed)
2. a question asking if there is anything similar to Bhutan's happiness index
3. a question about discretionary income
4. a question about how international rankings influence national policy
5. a question asking about links between political system and quality of life
6. a question asking about why economic growth is often considered essential.

What is the meaning of the [indicators](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicators) tag – and if there is none, should the tag be gotten rid of?

Answer (score 4):

The tags [indicators](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicators) and [measurement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) are somewhat related, in that an indicator is the result of measurement.

[Indicator](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indicator)

> 2 : any of a group of statistical values (such as level of employment) that taken together give an indication of the health of the economy

[Measurement](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/measurement)

> 2 : a figure, extent, or amount obtained by measuring

Thus, [indicators](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicators) is used to ask about certain results, whereas [measurement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) is sometimes used to ask about obtaining such results. Because the tag usage is similar to the common definitions, no excerpt (tag info) is required.

Indicators are often used in ranking countries for comparison purposes. Having the [indicators](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicators) tag is useful, even though rarely used.